# Why can't I execute my onClick after my OnclientClickEvent?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've the following function in javascript that calls a WebMethod that performs some server-side checkings:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function comprobar() 
{
PageMethods.F1
(
 $("input[type=text][id*=txt_nombre_nu]").val(),
 $("input[type=text][id*=txt_numero_empleado]").val(),
 $("input[type=text][id*=combo_empresa_nu]").val(),
 $("input[type=text][id*=txt_ceco]").val(),
 $("input[type=text][id*=combo_gestor_nu]").val(),
 $("input[type=text][id*=combo_crear_datos]").val(),
    function (msg) 
    {
    if (msg == "") 
       {
       alert("Datos correctos");
       return true;
       }
       else 
       {
       alert(msg);
       return false;
       }
    },
    function (msg) 
    {          
    }
 );
 }
 </script>
```

The function itself seems to execute properly, as, if data isn't correct it displays the alert with the right data

The point is that after this function is executed I need the event OnClick that executes server-side code to be executed. I know that another PageMethod could be created to execute code, problem is that the code that is needed to be called isn't static so I can't put it on a a WebMethod.

Anyway I have done the following checkings:

This is the button where I've the events defined:

```
<obout:OboutButton runat="server" ID="btn_mdu_confirmar" Text="Confirmar" CausesValidation="true"
       OnClientClick="comprobar();return false;" OnClick="btn_mdu_confirmar_Click"/>
```

I've checked that if return false then btn_mdu_confirmar_Click isn't executed but if I change it for return true; it's always executed after OnClientClickEvent. So, why doesn't something like OnClientClick="return comprobar();" or even OnClientClick="comprobar();"  not work and look like it always return a false a true value even if msg is differnt to ""?

It's something to notice that I haven't been able to debug the javascript code, but if it displays the alerts properly I see no real reason that a simple return statement would fail.

Hope you can help me with this, thanks for your time.

Comment: JavaScript Function object always returns `void` on default. You need to set `return true` in your function `comprobar()`

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated code in relation to your JS code:

```
function comprobar() 
{
 PageMethods.F1
  (
    $("input[type=text][id*=txt_nombre_nu]").val(),
    $("input[type=text][id*=txt_numero_empleado]").val(),
    $("input[type=text][id*=combo_empresa_nu]").val(),
    $("input[type=text][id*=txt_ceco]").val(),
    $("input[type=text][id*=combo_gestor_nu]").val(),
    $("input[type=text][id*=combo_crear_datos]").val(),
    function (msg) 
    {
       if (msg == "") 
       {
       alert("Datos correctos");
       return true;
       }
       else 
       {
       alert(msg);
       return false;
       }
   },
   function (msg) 
   {          
   }
);

return true; //now comprobar() always returns true;
}
```

Then this update in your HTML should do it:

```
<obout:OboutButton runat="server" ID="btn_mdu_confirmar" Text="Confirmar" CausesValidation="true"
   OnClientClick="return comprobar();" OnClick="btn_mdu_confirmar_Click"/>
```

You can check the outcome of the method `PageMethods.F1` and check if this is true or false and return the outcome at the end of `comprobar()`. I can't update my code with this since I don't know how `PageMethods.F1` works. (It isn't in your post).